# If |f| is (lebesgue) measurable, is f measurable?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If  $|f|$ is (lebesgue) measurable, does that imply that $f$ measurable? My intuition tells me that it doesn't but I don't know how to show that. Thanks

Comment: How do you know if a set is unmeasurable? Do you have any examples?

Comment: With the axiom of choice there are examples. For example the Vitali set $V$ (which is more or less a set of representatives for the equivalence relation $x\cong y$ if $x-y\in\mathbb Q$) is not measurable. And then, you can just take $\chi_V-1/2$ which has absolute value $1/2$ everywhere.
On the other hand, if you don't have any nonmeasurable set, it's getting hard ...

Comment: what about a complex valued function $f$?

Comment: Well, every real valued function is complex.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: a function $f$ taking on only values $\pm 1$ can behave very rudely, but we would have $|f| = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Pick any non-measurable set $A$. Define:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 &: x \in A \\
-1 &: x \not\in A
\end{cases}
$$

$|f| = 1$ is a constant function, hence measurable.
But the set $$\{x \in E: f(x) \ge 1\}=A$$ is not measurable so $f$ is seen to be non-measurable.